# How to get data in groupby like SQL having with pandas.

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have data like below.

```
id, name, password, note, num
 1, hoge, xxxxxxxx, aaaaa, 2     
 2, hoge, xxxxxxxx, bbbbb, 1     
 3, moge, yyyyyyyy, ccccc, 2     
 4, zape, zzzzzzzz, ddddd, 3
```

I would like to make framedata using groupby same name and password. In this case, 1,hoge and 2,hoge are treated as same data. Then I would like to get count 3 
 from num column. 
I tried like below.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
df2 = df1.groupby(['name','password']).count()
print(df2[df2[note] > 1])
```

It goes like this.

```
name, password, note, num
hoge, xxxxxxxx, 2, 2
```

How can I get sum of num value?

Answer (score 0):

I belive you need [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) or [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) for exclude `NaN`s rows with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new `Series` with same size like original `DaatFrame`, so possible filtering with `sum`:

```
s = df1.groupby(['name','password'])['note'].transform('size')

s = df1.groupby(['name','password'])['note'].transform('count')

out = df1.loc[s > 1, 'num'].sum()
print (out)
3
```

If want count only duplicated rows filter by [`DataFrame.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) with specify columns for check dupes:

```
out = df1.loc[df1.duplicated(['name','password'], keep=False), 'num'].sum()

print (out)
3
```